# Php script which checks if tax number has right company name on input some other form fields with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue in a PHP script which checks if the tax number has right company name on input some other form fields and insert into MySQL. What I want is to put some control code - maybe "select distinct formCompany from company where formCompany = ".$formCompany." " or some code which checks if  taxid is given correctly for the name of company from input form. Does someone have idea of how to do that? Any example is welcome.

I have script which simply input data from form fields into MySQL db:

```
$db=mysql_connect($hostname, $db_user, $db_password);
    mysql_select_db($database,$db);
$taxid=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['taxid']);
$formCompany=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['formCompany']);
$formOffice=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['formOffice']);
$formBr=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['formBr']);
$formContact=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['formContact']);
//trim
$id=trim($id);
$taxid=trim($taxid);
$formCompany=trim($formCompany);
$formOffice=trim($formOffice);
$formBr=trim($formBr);
$formContact=trim($formContact);
if($_POST['taxid']==''||$_POST['formCompany']=='') {
       echo '<p style="color: red">Input relevant data!<p>';
   } else { 
      $sql = "INSERT INTO company (taxid, formCompany,formOffice,formBr,formContact) VALUES ('$taxid','$formCompany','$formOffice','$formBr', '$formContact')";
   if(!$result = mysql_query($sql, $db)) {
      echo "ERROR: ".mysql_error();
   } else {
      header("Refresh: 0; url=main.php");
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, could you explain it a little better? Maybe some examples would help.

Comment: @Vitor42   If i input different formCompany name in form for that taxid then it is stored in mysql i have than two or more different names for one taxid which is unique number for one company. I must avoid that.

Comment: @mdakic - So, basically you want to check if the taxid already exists in your database? If that's correct, then check my answer below

Comment: @Tom and want to check that the $formTvrtka exactly same as in the database

Comment: $formTvrtka? You haven't put that in your code above. Please update your post with $formTvrtka and an overview of your database tables

Comment: @Tom i'm sorry! $formTvrtka is same as the $formCompany. My apologize  once again.

Comment: @mdakic - Ok! not a problem :) So everything works then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add this code before the if statement

```
$taxcheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company WHERE taxid = '" . $taxid . "' ");
if (mysql_num_rows($taxcheck)) { $exists = true; }
else { $exists = false; }
```

Then change this line

```
if($_POST['taxid']==''||$_POST['formCompany']=='')
```

to

```
if($_POST['taxid'] == "" || $_POST['formCompany'] == "" || $exists == true)
```

This code will prevent you from ending up with more than one company using one tax ID number.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, two companies - formCompany - in your app cannot have the same tax-id - taxid, right? If yes, the simplest way is to create a unique index on `company`.`taxid`. Any attempt then to insert another company with the same tax-id will thrown a MySQL error.

Here is the query for adding the unique index:

```
ALTER TABLE `company` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `idx_u_taxid` (`taxid`);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i'll check it if it is possible because taxid is not autoincrement an should not be because it is given by tax office. Does it need to be autoincrement or not - probably not.

Comment: It will work. It is not mandatory for a column to be auto-increment for a UNIQUE index. The UNIQUE index can be put on any column.